# Scrapy not scraping all intended urls when ran using default settings

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape urls of the form :

https://in.bookmyshow.com/XXXXX/cinemas : where 'XXXXX' is any city name. I have around 880 different city names in a file. And I want to scrap data from each of the url.

My Sample Code is as follows : https://www.jdoodle.com/a/u1E

File from which data is read is as follows : https://www.jdoodle.com/a/u1G

The problem that I am facing is that whenever I try to run scrapy using default settings, it runs asynchronously and concurrently. However, in doing so, it misses on half the urls that are to be scraped.

Also, if I run scrapy using settings mentioned in **option 2** : (see below). It scraps all the urls but this time it takes insane amount of time for completion.

Isn't there any way in which I can still run my script concurrently without losing any data to be scraped.

**Option 1:**

Settings : **Default**

*Stats :*

> 'downloader/request_count': 1331
>
> item_scraped_count': **444**
>
> Time to complete : 9 min

**Option 2:**

Settings : **{'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1, 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3}**

*Stats :*

> 'downloader/request_count': 1772
>
> item_scraped_count': 878
>
> Time to complete : **1hr-45min**

Comment: The question is: why is it missing urls? Does that website have a limited amount of requests you can perform? If so adjusting only the download delay may work, alternatively, you may have to use some proxy service like Crawlera or TOR

Comment: Adding a download delay does work. But increases the execution time of my script immensely. How can I know the rate of traffic that site can handle? Here's the link to robot.txt file https://in.bookmyshow.com/robots.txt  which doesn't allow to scrape the domain I am hitting. Also I am running my scripts in Widscribe VPN. Would you still suggest to use proxy service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your issue is not delay but concurrency. When you have 1 concurrent request per minute it works, when you have more it doesn't. Most likely reason of this is that the website is serving you content based on your cookies.

Try disabling cookies via `COOKIES_ENABLED` settings in your settings.py file:

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
```

If you see that content is not being served without cookies at all you need to use cookiejars to start multiple cookie instances that are working in parallel.

See: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Actually, my script is highly dependent on cookies, so disabling it is not an option (though I tried that as well).Though issue at hand looks like more of a 'delay'. Because when I ran using delay = 0 and concurrency = 1, spider only scraped 438 urls out of approx. 880 urls. However, when I ran using concurrency = 50 and delay = 1, it scraped all the pages. Cookie jar can be a solution but I will have to look for its implementation and working.

Comment: I don't how cookie jar manages to do that, but it does work. Thanks.